# .NET Exception "Object currently in use elsewhere" in clone object

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, serialization, locking

[image]

I am trying to create a byte array from the object. I have clone it but still encounter this exception. What is the problem here?

```cs
    class ByteInteract
    {
        Object tempObj;
        
        public ByteInteract(DataObj obj)
        {
            tempObj = (Object)obj.Clone();
        }

        public byte[] ToByteArray()
        {
            if (tempObj == null)
                return null;
            
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                lock (tempObj)
                {
                    ms.Flush();
                    bf.Serialize(ms, tempObj);
                }
            
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not post code as images

Comment: What is `DataObj`?

Comment: @GuruStron DataObj is my class. It's `Serializable` and implementing `ICloneable`

Comment: Googling the error "object currently in use elsewhere” shows manly problem involving `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, UI and multi-threading. Is that your case?

Comment: @EliahuAaron I'm having problem with multi-threading